# Error message popups have a greater z-index than the navigation bar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, top-bar, error-message

To reproduce this issue:

- make sure you did not [disable stickiness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current#fixedHeader);
- trigger a vote popup by

  - voting on your own post;
  - voting on a post on which your vote is already locked, or
  - downvoting something. This causes the popup asking for a comment.

Scroll down before that popup disappears, and you'll see that it is displayed over the navbar.

[image: A popup saying *you can't vote for your own post* is displayed on top of the navigation bar of Stack Overflow.]

This happens for all error popups.

[image: A popup saying *you last voted on this answer Aug 11 at 8:10, your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited* is displayed on top of the navigation bar of Stack Overflow. This popup is highlighted with a red freehand circle drawn on top of the screenshot.]

I'm not sure if this is intentional, but as a web developer, this doesn't seem like it is.

The error message has `z-index: 4000`, while the navbar has `z-index: 1050`.

Comment: This question would be better with a screenshot and a freehand red circle to indicate the area of concern.

Comment: I am not getting a popup at all

Comment: Why would you want the navigation bar to hide the error message? I'd wager this is intentional.

Comment: Be careful what you wish for, @Roddy ;-) Is this better?

Comment: @Stijn Typically the navbar is the "highest" thing on a page unless there's a modal. Everything else on the page is displayed under it, and (IMO) the error message should be no different.

Comment: This absolutely seems like something that would be intentional. The most critical element on the page should be at the top of the Z order, and an error message definitely qualifies. If an error message were to be hidden by a navigation bar, thus blocking it from site, then you would have a real bug. (Also, I could swear this was reported recently, but I don't see it anywhere…)

Comment: Tagging this [meta-tag:status-bydesign] because of what @CodyGray said.